# How to split NVARCHAR, converting the result into an int in SQL?

Tags: sql, split, integer, ssms, nvarchar

I'm trying to convert `nvarchar` separated with a comma to `int`, but I have a problem. I tried to use `PARSENAME(REPLACE())`, and it works fine but takes a long time to execute the code. I have a lot of tables, but here is an example.

I have a column that has name **value** and `nvarchar` datatype like (222,333,55,666,777,111). Every number will return **color id**, and then I use a function that will take converted value into text like(red/blue/green/black/gray). I want to split the value and convert the result into an `int`.

I have a function called `GetTextAllLevel(int value)` that takes `int` id and returns text. For example, it will take the value *222* and return **red**.

```sql
Tabel.GeTextAllLevels(CAST (Replace(Value, ',','.')) AS int) AS Category
```

I get syntax error at "AS", and I don't know why. I tried the code below that works with only four ids also:

```sql
GetCategoryLongName(((PARSENAME(REPLACE((fieldValue), ',', '.'),1)))) AS Category,
```

Comment: Never, ever store data as comma separated items. It will only cause you lots of trouble.

Comment: it is old database yhat I I work with. it is already exist.

Comment: Then fix the design, @rand

Comment: What do you mean@Larnu

Comment: I mean, why not fix the design? Because the database already stores delimited data doesn't mean that you then just ignore that problem; *fix* it. Normalise the design.